# If G is a group such that Aut(G) has only 1 element, then every element of G has finite order.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

We have to Prove or disprove this statement. Can somebody give a hint to proceed with this question?

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The group must be Abelian and the automorphism $x\mapsto x^{-1}$ must be the identity. Thus $x^2=1$ in that group. So the group is elementary abelian and the direct product of $n$ groups of order $2$. Since its automorphism group is the general matrix group of dim $n$  over the field of two elements, $n$ must be $0$ or $1$ and your group is trivial or of order $2$.

Comment: $n$ could also be $1$

Comment: Correct! Fixed it.

Comment: Just a follow up question, to show that the group is abelian do we have to show that for all x in G are mapped to $$axa^{-1} $$ for some a in G ?

Comment: @User_in: The map $x\mapsto axa^{-1}$ is an (inner) automorphism for any $a$ in any group.

Comment: Alright thanks for the hint, but how do we show $$ x = axa^{-1}$$ for this conjugation automorphism?

Comment: How do we show what?

Comment: @User_in If there is only one automorphism, then that's the identity (which is always an automorphism, trivially); so, given that $x\mapsto axa^{-1}$ is an automorphism, it must be the identity, whence $x=axa^{-1}$.

Answer (score 2):

First try to prove that the group is abelian by considering the inner automorphisms. Then try to see that whenever a group is abelian, the map $x\mapsto x^{-1}$ is an automorphism.